# How do I adjust the time Mac Mail takes to mark messages "read"?

Tags: macos, mac, mail.app

It takes a number of seconds before Mac Mail marks a message as "read". I would like for it to take no more than 0.5 seconds, though instantaneous would be best.

How can I adjust the time required to view a message before it is no longer considered "unread"?

Mac OS X, 10.9.4 and 10.10

Comment: Please clarify if you are referring to Mail.app on Mac OS X (and if so, what version of OS X) or iOS (and again, which version of iOS). Your question references Mac but the tags reference iPhone. Thanks.

Comment: Great point thank you. iPhone actually does a nice job at instantly marking messages as "read".

Comment: I just tested this and the messages were marked as read instantly, using OS X 10.10. There are apparently no user preferences for this, and Apple removed a "defaults" preference at least two major versions ago, so I am not sure why you are seeing a delay. Is your mailbox very large/are there a large number of messages present? Are you using POP3 or IMAP with your email provider?

Comment: Brilliant! I am using IMAP. I disconnected from the network and it started marking them "read" instantaneously. I suppose when connected it waits for the server to mark it first. Thanks!

Comment: I added an answer that summarizes the result. If you could "accept" it as the answer, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried quitting Mail, launching a Terminal and putting in

```
defaults write com.apple.Mail MarkAsReadDelay 0
```

Comment: The `0` in that answer is measured in seconds. In other words if you want Mail to wait a second before marking a message as read change `0` to `1`

Comment: Thank you!! Alas, at long last, this is the **real** answer. What is the default value of this setting, and must the value be an integer?

Comment: Does this work properly on Yosemite ? I tried the same function under 10.10.3 to set the delay to 3 secs, but it sets the read flag instantaneously.

Comment: Unfortunately **this no longer works in Yosemite**. Apple removed this setting.

Comment: Is there an equivalent in `El Capitan`/`Sierra`?

Comment: Not really sure how this was ever the accepted answer, as this never worked in Yosemite and the question was always about Yosemite. My answer is correct based on the fact the OP is using IMAP and going offline caused messages to be marked read instantly.

Comment: Mac OS 10.12.6. this works defaults write com.apple.Mail MarkAsReadDelay 0 Instantaneous message as "read" on a IMAP account while online. works perfectly

Comment: Apple!  Why did you remove this defaults option?!  You have quite literally made the software worse!  Now when I delete an email, Mac Mail automatically selects the next and marks it as read.. ..even though I haven't read it!  I've missed at least a dozen highly important new emails because of this.

Answer (score 2):

When utilizing an IMAP account, you may see a delay in marking read when connected to the mail server, as it issues the mark read command to the server first and waits for a response before doing so locally.

Comment: Good point - even with the local mail client marking it as read, there can be network delays to foil that quick action and revert the status to unread.